# Stream stdout from subprocess

Tags: deno

I'm running a Docker build as a subprocess in Deno and would like the stdout streamed to the parent stdout (Deno.stdout) so it's outputted straight away.

How can I achieve this?

Currently I have the following but it doesn't output anything until the subprocess has finished.

```
const p = Deno.run({
  cmd: ['docker', 'build', '.'],
  stdout: 'piped'
});

const stdout = await p.output();
await Deno.stdout.write(stdout);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not far off; you just need to start the process of piping the output *before* you await the process. There's some other optimizations you can make, like using `Deno.copy` to pipe the subprocess' output to the main process' stdout without copying stuff in memory for example.

```js
import { copy } from "https://deno.land/std@0.104.0/io/util.ts";

const cat = Deno.run({
  cmd: ["docker", "build", "--no-cache", ".", "-t", "foobar:latest"],
  cwd: "/path/to/your/project",
  stdout: "piped",
  stderr: "piped",
});

copy(cat.stdout, Deno.stdout);
copy(cat.stderr, Deno.stderr);

await cat.status();
console.log("Done!");
```

If you want to prefix each line with the name of the process it came from (useful when you have multiple subprocesses running, you can make a simple function that uses the std lib's `readLines` function and a text encoder to do that

```js
import { readLines } from "https://deno.land/std@0.104.0/io/mod.ts";
import { writeAll } from "https://deno.land/std@0.104.0/io/util.ts";

async function pipeThrough(
  prefix: string,
  reader: Deno.Reader,
  writer: Deno.Writer,
) {
  const encoder = new TextEncoder();
  for await (const line of readLines(reader)) {
    await writeAll(writer, encoder.encode(`[${prefix}] ${line}\n`));
  }
}

const cat = Deno.run({
  cmd: ["docker", "build", "--no-cache", ".", "-t", "foobar:latest"],
  cwd: "/path/to/your/project",
  stdout: "piped",
  stderr: "piped",
});

pipeThrough("docker", cat.stdout, Deno.stdout);
pipeThrough("docker", cat.stderr, Deno.stderr);
await cat.status();
console.log("Done!");
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Note: [`Deno.writeAll`](https://doc.deno.land/builtin/stable#Deno.writeAll) is deprecated. (Use `writeAll` from [https://deno.land/std/io/util.ts](https://deno.land/std@0.104.0/io/util.ts#L170))

Comment: `copy` from `std/io` is deprecated: https://deno.land/std@0.140.0/io/util.ts?s=copy: _"Use `copy` from `std/streams` instead: https://deno.land/std/streams"_

Answer (score 3):

## Update for 2023

Looks like the answers here are out of date. I believe this is the current way to pipe output from a sub-process's stdout/stder into Deno's stdout/stderr:

```js
const command = new Deno.Command("rsync", {
  args: ["--help"],
  cwd: "/tmp",
  stdout: "piped",
  stderr: "piped",
});

const process = command.spawn();

const { success, code, signal } = await process.status;

console.log(`done! success: ${success} code: ${code} signal: ${signal}`);

process.stdout.pipeTo(Deno.stdout.writable);
process.stderr.pipeTo(Deno.stderr.writable);
```

This is how I added a prefix to stdout/stderr. I then merged these into one readable stream:

```js
import {
  mergeReadableStreams,
} from "https://deno.land/std@0.202.0/streams/merge_readable_streams.ts";

const command = new Deno.Command("rsync", {
  args: ["--help"],
  cwd: "/tmp",
  stdout: "piped",
  stderr: "piped",
});

const process = command.spawn();

const { success, code, signal } = await process.status;

console.log(`done! success: ${success} code: ${code} signal: ${signal}`);

mergeReadableStreams(
  process.stdout
    .pipeThrough(new TextDecoderStream())
    .pipeThrough(
      new TransformStream({
        transform(chunk, controller) {
          controller.enqueue(`[OUT] ${chunk}`);
        },
      }),
    )
    .pipeThrough(new TextEncoderStream()),
  process.stderr
    .pipeThrough(new TextDecoderStream())
    .pipeThrough(
      new TransformStream({
        transform(chunk, controller) {
          controller.enqueue(`[ERR] ${chunk}`);
        },
      }),
    )
    .pipeThrough(new TextEncoderStream()),
).pipeTo(Deno.stdout.writable);
```

Comment: Yes, BUT [\`console.log\` right after pipe'ing stream to \`Deno.stdout.writable\` throws \`BadResource\` error](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/19653) because `pipeTo` closes the writable side `Deno.stdout` when it's done. You can call `pipeTo(writable, { preventClose: true, preventCancel: true, preventAbort: true})` to prevent this.

Answer (score 2):

The `p` stands for process, `Deno.run` [returns the process state](https://doc.deno.land/builtin/stable#Deno.run) upon return (not the stdout):

```
console.log(await p.status());
// { success: true, code: 0 }
```

Since you are awaiting the status, the stdout will not stream the output until the process has finished.

Try [using the process](https://doc.deno.land/builtin/stable#Deno.Process) like this:

```js
const p = Deno.run({ cmd, stderr: 'piped', stdout: 'piped' });
const [status, stdout, stderr] = await Promise.all([
  p.status(),
  p.output(),
  p.stderrOutput()
]);

console.log(new TextDecoder().decode(stdout)); // since it's returned as UInt8Array

p.close();
```

But it'll still wait until the sub process is done.

Comment: How is this different? I'm still not going to get the stdout until all the promises have resolved (after the subprocess has completed).

Comment: Ah, I see. You might need to feed a stream from the subprocess, and read it from the main process -- but I haven't seen any docs on how to do that